# How does the iterator works in following program

Tags: c++, list, stl, backtracking, maze

The following program is solving maze without recursion. Program is working but I'm unable to figure out how the iterator `iter` works.

there are two comments **line 19** and **line 21**. I tried printing the value of iterator its giving me

> {1,0,1,0,1,0,3,4,3,4}

and

> {1,0,2,1,0,2,1,3,0,4,3,5,4,3,5,7,4,8}`

respectively.

The `simpleMaze` in `main()` shows the connections between elements and path of maze. As 0 is connected to (1,3); 1 is connected to (0,2) and so on.

Iterator is used for traversing then why this program is giving such sequence also I'm unable to understand the flow of function `solveMaze`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

list<int> solveMaze(list<int> maze[],int start,int finish) {
    unordered_set<int> visited;
    list<int> path;

    path.push_back(start);
    int currentPoint=start;
    visited.insert(currentPoint);

    while(path.back()!= finish && path.empty() == false)     {
        list<int>::iterator iter = maze[currentPoint].begin();
        bool foundOutlet = false;
        cout<<*iter<<"\n";     //line 19
        while(iter!=maze[currentPoint].end() && (foundOutlet== false)) {
        cout<<*iter<<"\n";   //line 21
            if(visited.count(*iter)==0) {
                foundOutlet = true;
            }
            else {
                iter++;
            }
        }
        if(foundOutlet)
        {
            path.push_back(*iter);
            visited.insert(*iter);
        }
        else
        path.pop_back();
        currentPoint= path.back();
    }

    return path;
}


int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    list <int> simpleMaze[9],path;
    simpleMaze[0].push_back(1);
    simpleMaze[0].push_back(3);

    simpleMaze[1].push_back(0);
    simpleMaze[1].push_back(2);

    simpleMaze[2].push_back(1);

    simpleMaze[3].push_back(0);
    simpleMaze[3].push_back(4);
    simpleMaze[3].push_back(6);


    simpleMaze[4].push_back(3);
    simpleMaze[4].push_back(5);
    simpleMaze[4].push_back(7);

    simpleMaze[5].push_back(4);

    simpleMaze[6].push_back(3);

    simpleMaze[7].push_back(4);
    simpleMaze[7].push_back(8);

    simpleMaze[8].push_back(7);


    path = solveMaze(simpleMaze,0,8);

    list<int>::iterator it;
    for(it=path.begin();it!=path.end();++it)
    {
        cout<<*it<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The solution of the maze is

> 0 3 4 7 8

Comment: You need to give us more details. How is a maze defined? How is the maze you are working with looking alike? What the numbers you have given are meaning?

Comment: @LajosArpad I explained how elements are connected in the maze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 19, you print out the first position adjacent to the "current" position.

At line 21 you are printing out the locations connected to the "current" position that you consider. You only visit a position going forward if you have never visited it before.

If there are no unvisited "next" places, you know that the solution doesn't involve going through the "current" location, so you go back one step, and try later connections from there.

Following it through a few steps:

```
Start 
 At 0
  See 1, it is unvisited, go there
 At 1
  See 0, it is visited
  See 2, it is unvisited, go there
 At 2
  See 1, it is visited
  No more locations at 2, backtrack
 At 1
  See 0, it is visited
  See 2, it is visited
  No more locations at 1, backtrack
 At 0
  See 1, it is visited
  See 3, it is unvisited, go there
....
```

Comment: thanks, buddy!! sorry, I can't upvote because of low reputation.

Comment: I also want to know about maze[currentPoint].end() when i'm printing it at line 18(say) it's giving me {2,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,3,2}  when my current point is 5 then how is the end() 1?

Comment: end does not have an associated value in the vector. It is the position after the last value, that exists to denote that you have exhausted the elements. It is ill-formed to dereference it